Add Bullets points to New Line within a textarea
I have a textarea that I want users be able to input text in


<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 p-0">
  <div class="blu-heading">Clarification Remarks</div>
  <div class="table-responsive tabledesign">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sr.No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Remarks</th>
          <th scope="col">Date of Query</th>
          <th scope="col">User Remarks</th>
          <th scope="col">Date of Reply</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${lmApplicationRemarks}" var="doc" varStatus="status">
          <tr>
            <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
            <td>${doc.remarks}</td>
            <td>
              <fmt:formatDate value="${doc.dateQuery}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </td>
            <td>${doc.userRemarks}</td>
            <td>
              <fmt:formatDate value="${doc.dateReply}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>



now my output is like this
1. Please update full detailed address of the factory location on the application. 2. You are requested to submit suggested/estimated turnover from the project for the next 3-5 years. 3. You are requested to provide a declaration stating that the company abides by the Press No.
but i want
1. Please update full detailed address of the factory location on the application.
2. You are requested to submit suggested/estimated turnover from the project for the next 3-5 years.
3. You are requested to provide a declaration stating that the company abides by the Press No.

I do not fully understand your question. Please edit your post to add more detail. Perhaps include a screenshot of what is happening now.

"I have a textarea that I want users be able to input text in..." Where is this <textarea> ? Is it dynamically added? Is done by sorcery?

Looking at your current and desired output, will adding <br> between each bullet point do the job?

Are you actually talking about a <textarea> form control? Or are you just using that term for one of those table cells, that you are showing text content in? "now my output is like this" - so that means it is currently just plain text, containing line breaks? Then you likely either want to apply some formatting that replaces those with <br> elements, or apply white-space: pre-line

Please add a tag for whatever environment you are working in as the code you have given does not appear to be pure HTML/JS/CSS.

Use this JavaScript code. Auto add some string at starting point of lines of <textarea> elements with class="txtarea".


let stringChar = "■√•●⦿►☼☻"; // some string to add to lines.
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("txtarea");
for (let el = 0; el < x.length; el++) {
  let resultText = (x[el].value != "") ? stringChar : "";
  for (let a = 0; a < x[el].value.length - 1; a++) {
    if (x[el].value[a] == '\n') {
      resultText += "\n" + stringChar;
    } else {
      resultText += x[el].value[a];
    }
  }
  x[el].value = resultText;
}
.txtarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 5rem;
}
<textarea class="txtarea">
1. Please update full detailed address of the factory location on the application.
2. You are requested to submit suggested/estimated turnover from the project for the next 3-5 years.
3. You are requested to provide a declaration stating that the company abides by the Press No.
</textarea>

<textarea class="txtarea">
Please update full detailed address of the factory location on the application.
You are requested to submit suggested/estimated turnover from the project for the next 3-5 years.
You are requested to provide a declaration stating that the company abides by the Press No.
Please update full detailed address of the factory location on the application.
You are requested to submit suggested/estimated turnover from the project for the next 3-5 years.
You are requested to provide a declaration stating that the company abides by the Press No.
</textarea>



